# Unable to run google-chrome

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I am unable to run `google-chrome`. It gives me the following error

```
browser_main_loop.cc(272)] Gtk: cannot open display: :0.0
```

Any help is appreciated. I am trying to learn Linux.

Update: I used the following steps to install Chrome:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

added

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Saved and exited, then

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
sudo apt-key add linux_signing_key.pub
sudo apt update
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

Thanks

Comment: How did you install google-chrome?

Comment: followed the steps provided @ https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-google-chrome-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: There are two sets of instructions there. Which did you follow?

Comment: You provided a very confusing link.  Can you tell us what commands you performed on your computer to install Chrome?

Comment: updated my question with the details you asked for

Comment: It appears that both you and I were typing at the same time.  Look at my answer and follow those steps and you shouldn't have any problems.  Did you get any error messages when you run `sudo install google-chrome-stable` or when you ran `sudo update`?

Comment: No,  I did not get any errors. It was clean

Comment: In hat case, look for it in your Ubuntu Dash search.  It should already be there.

Answer (score 1):

**For Google Chrome**, the Download site is: http://google.com.  The download link is: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

Download it and follow the installation steps provided by Google.

Once you download it, you can go to your Download directory and install it from the commandline.

Perform these steps:

Bring up a terminal with these keys: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

At the go to the download directory with this command:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
```

Then run this on the file:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

As per your comment for the commandline download, run this:

```
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

The installer automatically updates the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and provides the public key.

After you have installed it, you can run it by typing **Chrome** in the Ubuntu Dash Search Button.

**Installing Chromium**

Chromium is an an opens source web browser based on and similar Google Chrome.  It's in the repository.  You don't have to download anything to install it.  Just run this command from the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

Comment: Thanks James. Can I download from the cli, If so, what are the steps for the same.

Comment: @annapbabu You ran the correct commands already. To reinstall Chrome, run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall chrome`

Comment: `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Comment: @wjandrea I'm sure the user (as I mentioned to a comment in his question, already have Google chrome installed.  He just needs to run it from the Ubuntu Start Button as mentioned in my answer.  I also tried to clarify the steps for others that may happen up the OP's question.