# unable to install google-chrome-stable

Tags: google-chrome

unable to install google-chrome-stable:E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg-configure-a'to correct the problem. help pl, novice. Thnx a lot.

Comment: We're somewhat limited in how we can help, after all we don't even know what OS & release you're using, nor what product (Server? Desktop?).  Have you ran what it suggested as that would fix the issue, or if it didn't reading the messages from that command. As we can't see that output, we've little details we can currently help with; except to ask what OS/product/release you're using & tell you to read the messages.  Paste that detail for us if you need our help.  eg.  Are you using a *supported* architecture for google-chrome; a *supported* release etc..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Comment: May this link help you:
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/884877/unable-to-run-google-chrome?rq=1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884877/unable-to-run-google-chrome?rq=1)